# cerbero unable to build gstreamer on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gstreamer, ubuntu-18.04

I have a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic beaver).

I got cerbero from, git://anongit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/cerbero

```
$ ./cerbero-uninstalled bootstrap
...
$ ./cerbero-uninstalled package gsteamer-1.0
...
configure: error: 
*** GLib requires a 64 bit type. You might want to consider
*** using the GNU C compiler.

Recipe 'glib' failed at the build step 'configure'
```

I would love to fix the problem.  I would settle for a pointer to get help with cerbero.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug at the head of cerbero.  Support for Ubuntu 18.04 is very new.  So, there is not much choice of versions to checkout.  I did this one,

```
$ git checkout 45bbe8f9
```

It is getting much further along in the compile.

Comment: how is your compilation going?
Mine is stuck at libtool. I try to skip recipe. But the process stuck at pkg-config.
How to solve this problem? Thanks.